# Slightly moving high dpi mouse prevents executing single and double clicks normally on 4k laptop

Tags: mouse, 4k-resolution, mouse-click, high-dpi, high-resolution

Problem is only on new 4k 17'' laptop. I use Windows 10. I use: UtechSmart Venus Gaming Mouse RGB Wired, 16400 DPI High Precision Laser Programmable MMO Computer Gaming Mice ( [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00FNKMVUO/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FNKMVUO) )

If I slightly move mouse between push down of mouse button and push up or between first and second clicks of double click then mouse does not execute single and double click respectively. When I use same mouse on old laptop (non 4k) and it behaves well but on my new 4k laptop one slight movement of mouse prevents it of executing of single and doable click which is very annoying.

**Question:** How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are registry keys to change the double click response area.

http://win.tweaklibrary.com/Hardware/Input_Output-Device/20/Change-the-mouse-double-click-response-area/10003/

> Description:
>
> The mouse double-click operation is done in a specific area. Windows recognizes that you are double-clicking something when the height and width of the response area is known. It will process two mouse clicks as a double-click when maximum allowed distance between each click is specified.
>
> Registry Entry Details:
>
> Registry Entry 1 :
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse]
>
> Value Name :
>
> DoubleClickWidth
>
> Data Type :
>
> REG_SZ (String Value)
>
> Size in Pixels (like '400')

Comment: It works! Life with 4k display is much more easy now. But I recommend to set value much more than 400 (was not enough for me). I just set 5000 and it works really well. Is there a way to change also that Chrome browser will initiate drag of the link in more distance that it is now?

Comment: I posted new question regarding it: https://superuser.com/questions/1441540/slightly-moving-pressed-button-on-high-dpi-mouse-causes-initiate-drug-too-early