# Slightly moving pressed button on high dpi mouse causes initiate drug too early when in fact I want to execute click on 4k laptop

Tags: mouse, 4k-resolution, mouse-click, high-dpi, high-resolution

*Related question with answer on close but slightly different topic: [Slightly moving high dpi mouse prevents executing single and double clicks normally on 4k laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/1441472/slightly-moving-high-dpi-mouse-prevents-executing-single-and-double-clicks-norma/1441526#1441526)*

Problem is only on new 4k 17'' laptop. I use Windows 10. I use: UtechSmart Venus Gaming Mouse RGB Wired, 16400 DPI High Precision Laser Programmable MMO Computer Gaming Mice ( [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00FNKMVUO/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FNKMVUO) )

When I want to perform mouse click and I slightly move mouse while button is push down system is initiating drug before I push up. The distance of initiating drug is too small. When I use same mouse on old laptop (non 4k) and it behaves well but on my new 4k laptop one slight movement of mouse prevents it of executing of single click which is very annoying.

This is the solution for desktop only but not affects drug and drop in applications: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-drag-and-drop-in-windows

This is api to use in programming to make custom drag and drop area in your application: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090410-00/?p=18583

**Question:** How to increase drag and drop initiation area in applications?

Comment: look in your Mouse control panel > pointer options > 'Enhance pointer precision'

Comment: @Tetsujin It is off. Turning it on negatively affects gaming.

Comment: I think that HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop and KEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse are best answers to this question. I wonder why not many people have such problem, since mouse precision is becoming higher all the time.